# What are some promising areas of research in digital signal processing?

Tags: reference-request

I intend to pursue a PhD program in digital signal processing (DSP). However, it seems nowadays that research has saturated in DSP and it's all about machine learning and deep learning. Are there are any areas in pure DSP that can still be explored for a PhD? If so, what are some research groups that focus on these areas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choosing a novel topic is a bold and wise move. Your question requires a bit of a bet, yet it is interesting to me, as I have not thought about this for a while. I will first drop two dual thoughts (they could be updated):

- **shed light on black-boxes**: the present successes of machine learning and deep networks shall not make us forger that signals are our (DSP community) sensing door to a globally unknown world. *Truly understanding* what we can understand with data and models remains at our core, and we can be much better at that (to make it more interpretable, robust, model-based, explainable, reliable etc.)
- **save electrons in devices and computations**: sensing and computing are becoming pervasive (IoT, etc.), and this requires materials (from the extraction of rare-earth elements for sensors and computing devices) and resources (form energy-harvesting sensing to bit-wise or qubit-related fast algorithms). *Saving power* (efficient filters, compression, fast algorithms, etc.) are in our DNA.

DSP is a blended field of knowledge, where people of mixed origins (computing, acquisition, information theory, physics, optimization, computer vision, statistics) meet. I hope that we DSP people can innovate here.

Additional stuff, as they come:

- [The Future of Signal Processing: conference program (2017)](https://futureofsp.eecs.mit.edu/program/)

Comment: I completely agree with your point that we should "shed light on black-boxes". I have tried to look around for groups that explore [interpretable machine learning](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/), but unfortunately, there are very few and those that do are not taking on PhD students at this time. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: There are many avenues to interpretability in machine learning and deep networks. Some rely on transforms (scattering networks) some on optimization (regularity conditions), some on geometry (manifolds), some on physics (ML & PDE), and many others. I am pretty sure that there are many open positions in those areas

Comment: @mhdadk my PhD position happens to be pretty much exactly that: explainable / _reliable machine learning_ (at least in how it was officially advertised). The way I got it was by having a background from physics plus experience in CS (this is an informatics institute), that convinced them. If you're applying for a similar position, strong DSP foundations are probably a similarly good selling point. This may also work if you're applying for an ML position that's not specifically focused on interpretability or so – after all, a PhD is _supposed_ to involve own ideas on the research direction.

Comment: (Just note that to actually _publish_ in the AI field, you won't get far with mostly theoretical DSP arguments... all that really convices reviewers there is _results on real-world data_.)

Comment: @LaurentDuval do you know of any papers/references that discuss these different approaches to interpretability?

Comment: Let me add some in a couple of days